# Unable to checkin a project into SVN using SubEclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, plugins

I'm suing Mac 10.7.3, Eclipse Indigo, SubEclipse 1.8, SVN 1.7, and the Java HL interface.  I created an SVN repository, and want to check in a project, not previously checked in.  When I right click on my project, select "Team", "Share Project", and then follow the prompts.  I'm never asked for credentials to access the repository, and then project creation dies with ...

```
mkdir --parents -m "Initial import." [https://svn.myconewmedia.org/svn/repo/csf/trunk/correlations]
    URL access forbidden for unknown reason
svn: Access to '/svn/repo/!svn/act/19defd24-393a-4997-bc9e-3c624425a1d4' forbidden
```

Although I entered a username and password when I setup the repo, I assumed this information wasn't cached.  Does anyone know how I can checkin my project using Eclipse?

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between setting up a repository (which uses `svnadmin create`) and creating a working directory (which you do via Subversion's command line client -- `svn co` or via Ecilpse's built in Subversion client.

You said you gave it a user and password *I entered a username and password when I setup the repo*. What do you mean by that?

Can you checkout from the repository using the Subversion command line? If so, the issue is with Eclipse and the Subversion client. I've had issues with Java HL in the past because it requires the Subversion C API. Instead, I use [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/) which is a pure Java solution, and doesn't require the Subversion C API. This is especially good to know if you're using a Mac because Apple doesn't provide the Subversion API libraries. See [ColabNet JavaHL page](http://bit.ly/JOIeIf) for more information.

I also recommend you look at [CollabNet Desktop Edition](http://desktop-eclipse.open.collab.net/). It has everything you need, and has a much better merge client than the standard Eclipse merge client.

---

## Response

> I can checkout fine from the command line, so yes, I believe the problem is with Eclipse. I installed SVNKit in Eclipse, but how do I "use" it within Eclipse? When I open the Preferences -> SVN dialog, there is no "SVNKit" checkbox, only a "JavaHL: Commit across multiple projects automatically" checkbox, which is checked.

Okay, I downloaded Eclipse on my Mac, and then installed under *Help->Install New Software...*, the CollabNet Desktop (http://downloads.open.collab.net/eclipse/update-site/e3.5), Subclipse ( http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x) and SVNKit (http://eclipse.svnkit.com/1.7.x).

I then restarted Eclipse, and went to *Eclipse->Preferences...*. From there, I chose, *Team*, and under *Team*, *SVN*. Part way down the screen, there's a *SVN Interface* entry. In the *Client* field, I selected *SVNKit (Pure Java)*.

I then right clicked and said *New->Project* and selected SVN. I created a new repository, and was able to check out from that repository.

Are you able to follow these instruction? Is there something different? Do you see the *SVN Interface* preference? You have to change it from JavaHL to SVNKit.

Comment: I can checkout fine from the command line, so yes, I believe the problem is with Eclipse.  I installed SVNKit in Eclipse, but how do I "use" it within Eclipse?  When I open the Preferences -> SVN dialog, there is no "SVNKit" checkbox, only a "JavaHL: Commit across multiple projects automatically" checkbox, which is checked.

Comment: @Dave See my response after my initial posting